# File "D:\rytm 2.1\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped

Tags: python, discord.py, bots

I'm making a bot for a music discord and it gives errors.

Error:

```
Ignoring exception in command play:
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "D:\rytm 2.1\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)`enter code here`
  File "D:/rytm 2.1/main.py", line 33, in play

    name_channel = author.voice.channel.name
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'channel'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\rytm 2.1\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
    enter code here

  File "D:\rytm 2.1\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 863, in invoke

    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "D:\rytm 2.1\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped

    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'channel'
Ignoring exception in command play:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\rytm 2.1\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped

    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:/rytm 2.1/main.py", line 40, in play
    voice.channel = discord.utils.get(server.voice.channels, name=name_channel)
AttributeError: 'Guild' object has no attribute 'voice'
```

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\rytm 2.1\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 939, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "D:\rytm 2.1\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 863, in invoke

    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "D:\rytm 2.1\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped

    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Guild' object has no attribute 'voice'
```

Code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from config import  token

import youtube_dl
import os

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Bot online!')

server, server_id, name_channel = None, None, None

domains = ['https://www/youtube.com', 'https://www/youtube.com/','http://youtu.be/']
async def check_domains(link):
    for x in domains:
        if link.startswith(x):
            return True
        return False


@bot.command()
async def play(ctx, *, command = None):
    """включает музыку"""
    global server, server_id, name_channel
    author = ctx.author
    if command == None:
        server = ctx.guild
        name_channel = author.voice.channel.name
        voice.channel = discord.utils.get(server.voice.channels, name = name_channel)
    params = command.split('  ')
    if len(params) == 1:
        file_name = params[0]
        server = ctx.guild
        name_channel = author.voice.channel.name
        voice.channel = discord.utils.get(server.voice.channels, name=name_channel)
        print('param 1')
    elif len(params) == 3:
        server_id = params[0]
        voice_id = params[1]
        file_name = params[2]
        try:
            server_id = int(server_id)
            voice_id = int(voice_id)
        except:
            await ctx.chanell.send(f'{author.mention},  id сервера или войса должно быть целочисленным')
            return
        print('paras 3')
        server = bot.get_guild(server_id)
        voice_channel = discord.utils.get(server.voice_channels, id=voice_id)
    else:
        await ctx.chanell.send(f'{author.mention} команда не корректна!')
        return

    voice = discord.utils.get(bot.voice_clients, guild = server)
    if voice is None:
        await voice_channel.connect()
        voice = discord.utils.get(bot.voice_clients, guild=server)

        if sourse == None:
            pass
        elif sourse.startswithh('http'):
            if check_domains(sourse):
                await ctx.channel.send(f'{author.mention} ссылка не является разрешенной')
                return
            song_there = os.path.isfile('music/song.mp3')
            try:
                if song_there:
                    os.remove('song.mp3')
            except PermissionError:
                await ctx.channel.send('Недостаточно прав для удаления файла!')
            ydl_opts = {
                'format': 'bestaudio/best',
                'postprovessors': {
                    {
                        'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
                        'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
                        'preferredguality': '192',
                    }
                }
            }

            with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
                ydl.download([source])
            for file in os.listdir('music/'):
                if file.endswith('mp3'):
                    os.rename(file, 'song.mp3')
                    voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio('song.mp3'))
    else:
        voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(f'music/{source}'))

bot.run(token)
```

Comment: [`author.voice.channel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.VoiceState.channel) will return `None` if the user that called the command it not connected to a voice channel.

Comment: So if the user was connected to the voice channel and gives errors when you write command play

Comment: If you get a different error if the user is connected, feel free to update your question to include the new error.